# Max possible requests per second performed with OkHttp client

Tags: java, okhttp

I'm trying to configure OkHttp Client to be able to send as many HTTP requests per second as possible.

I have the following configuration:

```
public static OkHttpClient getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            instance = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(createHttpBodyLoggingInterceptor())
                    .addInterceptor(createHttpBasicLoggingInterceptor())
                    .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .dispatcher(createDispatcher())
                    .connectionPool(createConnectionPool())
                    .build();
        }
    }
    return instance;
}

private static Dispatcher createDispatcher() {
    final Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
    dispatcher.setMaxRequests(64);
    dispatcher.setMaxRequestsPerHost(64);
    return dispatcher;
}

private static ConnectionPool createConnectionPool() {
    return new ConnectionPool(64, 10_000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

I have simple performance/integration test, which executes multiple asynchronous requests to the server. One instance of the HTTP client is executing requests to the one instance of HTTP server on the same machine.

I know that value 64 is default value for `maxRequests`. I tried to increase this value as well as other values (e.g. `maxRequestsPerHost` or number of connections in `ConnectionPool`), but no matter what I set above these value (e.g. 100 or 1000), I'm able to process only around ~45 requests per second. Other requests are failing and I'm getting `SocketTimeoutException`.
Do you know if it's possible to configure OkHttp to be able to process more requests than 45 per second? Or there are software or hardware limitations, which prevent that?

I'll appreciate any answers or ideas.

Regards,
Piotr

Comment: Probably worth removing any additional work, remove the logging interceptor.  You may also want to see if doing some explicitly load balancing across okhttp client instances (normally an antipattern) can increase your throughput.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I need logs in the system, so logging interceptors cannot be removed. I also tried to test this idea with load balancing across client instances. In my test I was choosing clients randomly, but the result was exactly the same as previously and throughput wasn't increased. I tried it e.g. for 4 clients, 50, 100, 1000. In each case, results were the same.

Comment: Use ~100 threads to saturate your CPU, or more if the responses have high latency. Given a fast enough server and network, you should be able to achieve 10K QPS without much tuning. With tuning 100K QPS or more is possible.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @JesseWilson. Taking into consideration your comment, to use 100 threads properly with OkHttp, I should use fixed thread pool with 100 threads (instead of cached thread pool) and pass it into Dispatcher to improve performance?

Comment: Should I also update max requests, max requests per host and connection pool configuration after updating thread pool configuration to create correct setup?

Comment: Yes, those updates all sound great.

Comment: And you don't need to change the ExecutorService on the Dispatcher. That'll scale up as you adjust the other parameters.

Comment: Ok, so I'll change these 3 parameters from 64 to 100 and deploy it later to the server. On my laptop, I'm not able to observe any difference, but maybe in the production environment it'll be significant. Thanks.

Comment: I used Cached Thread Pool ExecutorService because according to the Java documentation: It "creates a thread pool that creates new threads as needed, but will reuse previously constructed threads when they are available. These pools will typically improve the performance of programs that execute many short-lived asynchronous tasks.", so I thought that will be the best choice in my case, but I see internal implementation of the ExecutorService inside OkHttp is similar to this one.

Answer (score 1):

The fact you are getting AROUND 45 requests per second probably means that it`s a hardware limitation. Also, the AROUND is probably due to network connectivity or something of the same nature.